# Removing "\n" character while writing into a file in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, bash-completion, yad

Here i am taking the text input from the yad ui field and then i am writing that text into a solc.c but that text contains some \n characters , which are directly being written into solc.c

```
#!/bin/bash


language=$(yad --form --field="Select Language:CB" "C!C++" --button="OK:0" --button="Cancel:1" --width=300 --height=100)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  selected_language=$(echo "$language" | awk -F"|" '{print $1}')

  code=$(yad --form --field="Your Code:TXT" --title="Problem-A Solution" --button="OK:0" --button="Cancel:1" --width=800 --height=600)

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    if [ "$selected_language" = "C" ]; then
      "${code%?}" > "solc.c"  
      gcc solc.c
    elif [ "$selected_language" = "C++" ]; then
      "${code%?}" > "sol1.cpp"  
      g++ sol1.cpp
    else
      echo "Invalid language selected."
      exit 1
    fi
```

current solc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>\n\nint main() {\n    long long a, b;\n    scanf("%lld %lld", &a, &b);\n    printf("%lld\\n", a + b);\n    return 0;\n}\n
    return 0;\n }\n
```

expected :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    long long a, b;
    scanf("%lld%lld", &a, &b);
    printf("%lld\n", a + b);
    return 0;
}
```

it worked sometime but for the same code it is not working now,
and same it follows with sol1.cpp

Also mention ,if there is any other hacks to get rid of the `\n` being written into the file .

Comment: could you update the question to show the contents of `code` (eg, output from `typeset -p code`)

Comment: `code` contains same as what current sol.c(mentioned above) contains, with extra `|` at the end ,which i tried to remove by writing as `"${code%?}"`  to the solc.c file

Comment: is there any other way to write the text from yad text field to a cpp or c file?

Comment: `"${code%?}" > "solc.c"` says to execute whatever `${code%?}` returns and place the output in `solc.c`; you're saying `code` contains the string `#include ...` but if bash tries to execute that you get an error message; so either `${code}` doesn't contain what you say it does or the script you've provided isn't your real script (eg, does your real script *echo* the variable - `echo "${code%?}" > "solc.c"`?)

Comment: how does `${code}` end up generating two sets of `return 0;\n }\n` (current contents of `solc.c`)?

Comment: We want you to update the question with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're asking for help to debug and nothing else, see [ask]. Posting snippets of code that aren't your real code and can't possibly do what you say they do isn't useful for us to be able to help you debug your problem.

Comment: to get `echo` to process the `\n` as a linefeed try `echo -e "${code%?}"`; you can do something similar with `printf`'s `%b` => `printf "%b" "${code%?}"`; this would've been easier/quicker to point out had we been presented with a valid, working script

Comment: seems like many didnot understand the question , its my mistake i asked in minimal reproducible form,I would have asked with all the context, uploading the complete project it seems. but i am glad somebody answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert the string "\n" into the actual character `\n`:

```
code=$(yad --form \
      --field="Your Code:TXT" \
      --title="Problem-A Solution" \
      --button="OK:0" \
      --button="Cancel:1" \
      --width=800 \
      --height=600 | 
         sed 's/\\n/\n/g')
```

You can now do (you really don't want to use `echo` for unsanitized input like that, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22222); and your code was trying to execute the `$code` variable instead of saving to a file)

```
printf '%s\n' "$code" > solc.c
```